# Linq to SQL translation Failing as well as Local Evaluation

Tags: c#, sql, linq, .net-core, linq-to-sql

Okay, so I have the following linq to sql query:

```
var baseQuery = _context.AuditTransaction
    .Include(at => at.AuditEntityEntries)
    .ThenInclude(aee => aee.AuditPropertyEntries)
    .Where(at => auditTransactionFilter.Id == 0 || at.Id == auditTransactionFilter.Id)
    .Where(at =>
        string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(auditTransactionFilter.UserName) ||
        at.UserName == auditTransactionFilter.UserName);


return baseQuery
    .Where(at => at.AuditEntityEntries.Any() || at.AuditEntityEntries
        .Any(ataee => auditTransactionFilter.AuditEntityEntries
            .Any(atfaee =>
                (atfaee.Id == 0 || ataee.Id == atfaee.Id) &&
                (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(atfaee.TableName) ||
                    ataee.TableName.ToLower().Contains(atfaee.TableName.ToLower()))
                &&
                (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(atfaee.KeyValues) ||
                    ataee.KeyValues.ToLower().Contains(atfaee.KeyValues.ToLower()))
                && (atfaee.AuditPropertyEntries.Any() || ataee.AuditPropertyEntries
                    .Any(atape => atfaee.AuditPropertyEntries
                        .Any(atfape =>
                            (atfape.Id == 0 || atape.Id == atfape.Id) &&
                            (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(atfape.PropertyName) ||
                                atape.PropertyName == atfape.PropertyName)
                            &&
                            (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(atfape.AuditType.ToString()) ||
                                atape.AuditType == atfape.AuditType)
                            &&
                            (atfape.PropertyValues == null ||
                                atape.PropertyValues.Contains(atfape.PropertyValues))
                        ))
                    )
            )

        ));
```

For whatever reason, when it runs, i get hundreds of warnings that various parts of it can't be translated and will be evaluated locally.  However, the query runs and does not properly filter out non-matches: returning all records in the DB.

However, when I return baseQuery.ToList().Where(...) the query runs perfectly.

Update: Even a simple query such as:

```
return baseQuery
     .Where(at => at.AuditEntityEntries.Any(ataee => auditTransactionFilter.AuditEntityEntries.Any(atfaee => atfaee.TableName == ataee.TableName)));
```

returns errors like this:

```
warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[20500]
      The LINQ expression 'where ([atfaee].TableName == [ataee].TableName)' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[20500]
      The LINQ expression 'Any()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[20500]
      The LINQ expression 'where {from AuditEntityEntry atfaee in __auditTransactionFilter_AuditEntityEntries_0 where ([atfaee].TableName == [ataee].TableName) select [atfaee] => Any()}' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[20500]
      The LINQ expression 'where ([atfaee].TableName == [ataee].TableName)' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[20500]
      The LINQ expression 'Any()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[20500]
      The LINQ expression 'where  ?= (Property([at], "Id") == Property([ataee], "AuditTransactionId")) =?' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[20500]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Please help.

Comment: *"when it runs, i get hundreds of warnings"* You are getting warnings at runtime?

Comment: Also, the `Where` clause on your `return` statement can be simplified to the first condition, since the second part of the `||` is a filtered version of the first one (if the first is `true`, then the second will always be `true`). You can simplify it to `return baseQuery.Where(at => at.AuditEntityEntries.Any()`.

Comment: @Rufus, Warnings come during runtime when the query executes.  And thanks, I've modified all of the redundant null safetychecks to just .Any().  I'm still getting the warnings.

Comment: Also, I've added a simple attempt at a nested iteration, and it's failing.  I updated the question to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, well, I got sick and tired with trying to find ways around linq to sql nested Any() statements, So, I pulled in a predicateBuilder Library from LinqKit.

```
var baseQuery = _context.AuditTransaction
    .Include(at => at.AuditEntityEntries)
        .ThenInclude(aee => aee.AuditPropertyEntries)
    .Where(at => auditTransactionFilter.Id == 0 || at.Id == auditTransactionFilter.Id)
    .Where(at => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(auditTransactionFilter.UserName) || at.UserName == auditTransactionFilter.UserName);


var queryPredicateBuilder = PredicateBuilder.New<AuditTransaction>();

foreach (var entityFilter in auditTransactionFilter.AuditEntityEntries)
{
    if(entityFilter.AuditPropertyEntries?.Count == 0)
    {
        queryPredicateBuilder
            .Or(at => at.AuditEntityEntries
                    .Any(ataee => ataee.TableName.Contains(entityFilter.TableName)
                    && (ataee.KeyValues == entityFilter.KeyValues || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(entityFilter.KeyValues))));
    }
}

foreach (var propertyFilter in auditTransactionFilter.AuditEntityEntries.SelectMany(atfaee => atfaee.AuditPropertyEntries))
{
    queryPredicateBuilder
        .Or(at => at.AuditEntityEntries
            .Any(ataee => ataee.TableName.Contains(propertyFilter.AuditEntityEntry.TableName)
            && (ataee.KeyValues == propertyFilter.AuditEntityEntry.KeyValues || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyFilter.AuditEntityEntry.KeyValues))
            && ataee.AuditPropertyEntries
                .Any(atape => atape.PropertyName == propertyFilter.PropertyName && atape.PropertyValues.Contains(propertyFilter.PropertyValues))
        ));
}
return baseQuery.AsExpandable().Where(queryPredicateBuilder);
```

And that totally did the trick!
I don't like it, but it works and I'm not sure how else to generate a dynamic linq to sql statement that will translate correctly and have this many levels of nested any checks against an outside list of non-primitives.

I'm still up for better answers.